# align text middle with position: absolute

Tags: jquery, css, absolute

I'm using jRumble  a jquery plugin to make my text shake.

I want it to activate on-hover, but only if you hover of the text (not the div!) so, I use `position: absolute;`

Because I use `position:absolute;` my text aligns at left, instead of middle!

without absolute:
http://jsfiddle.net/UxS6y/

with absolute:
http://jsfiddle.net/UxS6y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the fiddle, and if you make the following changes it should work:

```
/* In style sheet */
.center {
    text-align:center;
}

#cv {
    /* add this on top of what is there*/
    display:inline-block;
}

/* remove the absolute */
<div class="center"> 
    <span id="cv">CV</span>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UxS6y/3/)

Comment: Perfect! I have another piece of text on the right side, with the same problem, I just replace center with right i assume?

Comment: Yep as a general rule (a very general rule), add an outer container to control alignment, then have an inner interact-able element, in this case your hover button. So yes text-align right would work. If my answer helped, don't forget to upvote/mark correct :D

Comment: Hey, I've added an image to the div. The text drops down to the bottom of the div together with the image. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you add it to the fiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, I've fixed it myself after a 2nd glance at the code. (I changed something you originally posted.)

Answer (score 0):

The containing div will need a specified width with absolute as it doesn't take up the whole screen. So if you set it (#absolute) to width:100%; it should work.

Comment: It aligns to center-right now + being hoverable on the entire div instead of only the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the div to the center of the screen using `left`

```
#absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -11px;/*half the width of the div*/
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, the only problem is that it moves a little more to the bottom (eh?)